# Checking to see if a value at a position in a dataframe meets a certain condition, but getting Key Error: 0 each time

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently trying to perform a simple comparison of values on my dataframe, and appending a value to a list based on whether or not the comparison is true or not. If the value contained in `test` is greater than  or equal to 4, I want to just append 4, but if the value is less than 4, I want to append the value in the dataframe instead. This is my current code:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"test":[12, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 10, 9]} 

oxygen = []
for i in range(0,len(data.index)):
    if (data['test'][i] >= 4):
        oxygen.append(4)
    else:
        oxygen.append(data['test'][i])
```

My desired output would look something like this:

```
print(oxygen)

[4,4,4,4,1,3,2,4,4,4]
```

However, my code when ran, gives me this error:

```
KeyError: 0
```

Where am I going wrong here? I'm thinking it's something to do with the value in the dataframe I'm trying to compare it to?

Comment: Use `df.test.clip(upper=4)`

Comment: Or : `import numpy as np; np.where(data['test']>4 , 4, data['test'])`